# Implement jwt token in the url

Tags: codeigniter, jwt, codeigniter-3

I need your help if possible,
I already have the library installed, I added the code but I can't generate the token and concatenate it with my URL,

**Thank you for all your help, I'm sorry for the mistakes, it's my first time on the forum.**

**This is the integration of the JWT library into my code**

the specific part I'd like assistance with is on Line 35: $response[$i]['file_url'] = $video['file_url'];

This is the desired outcome:
file_url = https://myvideo.com/video.mp4?token=jwt

I want to concatenate a JWT token to the file_url. Can you please guide me on how to achieve this?

Thank you for your assistance!

Relevant part of the code:
Codigniter version 3

```
<?php
require_once '/www/wwwroot/premium.portkks.net/vendor/autoload.php';
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$secretKey = "mysecretkey"; // Secret key

// Actual time
$issuedAt = time();
// exp time
$expirationTime = $issuedAt + (3 * 60 * 60); // 3 h

$payload = [
    "iat" => $issuedAt,       // "Issued at" - 
    "exp" => $expirationTime  // "Expiration time" 
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $secretKey, 'HS256');
?>

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

     function get_all_video_by_movie_id($videos_id){
        $response   =   array();
        $this->db->order_by('order', $this->video_file_order());
        $this->db->where('videos_id',$videos_id);
        $query      = $this->db->get('video_file');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0):
            $videos = $query->result_array();
            $i      =   0;
            foreach ($videos as $video):
                $response[$i]['video_file_id']                  = $video['video_file_id'];
                $response[$i]['label']                          = strtoupper($video['label']);
                $response[$i]['stream_key']                     = $video['stream_key'];
                $response[$i]['file_type']                      = $video['file_source'];
                $response[$i]['file_url']                       = $video['file_url'];
                $response[$i]['subtitle']                       = $this->get_all_movie_subtitle($video['video_file_id']);
                if($video['file_source'] =='gdrive'):
                    $response[$i]['file_type']          = 'embed';
                    //$response[$i]['label']              = 'GOOGLE';
                elseif($video['file_source'] =='amazone'):
                    $response[$i]['file_type']          = 'mp4';
                elseif($video['file_source'] =='m3u8'):
                    $response[$i]['file_type']          = 'hls';
                elseif($video['file_source'] =='vimeo'):
                    $response[$i]['file_type']          = 'embed';
                    $response[$i]['file_url']           = str_replace('vimeo','player.vimeo',$video['file_url']);
                    $response[$i]['file_url']           = str_replace('.com/','.com/video/',$response[$i]['file_url']);
                endif;
                $i++;
            endforeach;
        endif;
        return $response;
    }
```

This is the result I would like.
This is the desired outcome: file_url = https://myvideo.com/video.mp4?token=jwt

Comment: Could you please narrow down the code and the tags to only what is important for your question? Which version of CodeIgniter are you using? That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Done, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to concatenate the values like this:

```
$response[$i]['file_url'] = $video['file_url'] . '?token=' . $jwt;
```